# Overriding input default behavior - Controlled <input /> element value and onChange event in VueJS

Tags: html, vue.js, input, vuejs3

Coming from React, I am used to the concept of taking "control" of an html element value and events.

I am looking to do the same with VueJS.

I have, an input:

```
<input :value="foo" @input="changeFoo" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">
```

A computed value coming from my VueX store:

```
...mapState({
 foo: (state) => state.foo,
}),
```

A method that commits a mutation to my VueX state

```
changeFoo(e) { this.$store.commit('CHANGE_FOO', e.target)}
```

A mutation that updates the state if the regex pattern matches

```
CHANGE_FOO(state, target) {
  if (target.checkValidity()) {
    state.foo = target.value;
  }
 },
```

What works:

- my VueX state updates
- my input updates
- if checkValidity returns `false`, the store is not updated

**What doesn't work:**

- even if the store is not updated, the `<input />` value changes... What I want is bind a single source of truth to my `<input />` component

Comment: "even if the store is not updated, the `<input />` value changes" - how does it change?

Comment: as if there was no regex pattern. So I find myself with 2 conflicting values:

Comment: my VueX store will have for example "hello world" and my input value will be "hello world!" ("!" not matching the regex)

Comment: So I think my problem has nothing to do with VueX. It shall behave the same with a setter, found this npm package to solve it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pattern-input. I am quite intrigued, there is no other way in VueJS to set a single source of controlled truth to an html element?

Comment: You may need to prevent the default behavior at different point, for example as soon as the validity check fails.

Comment: yes I tried `e.preventDefault()` directly in my method (so as soon as the onChange event fires, but the <input /> keeps updating)

Comment: also tried .prevent, .stop, stopPropagation()

Comment: Hm, wait, are we talking about restricting certain keystrokes (when the regex doesn't match) here though? If so, have you tried input masking? Vue 2 has something for that. UI frameworks like Vuetify and Quasar also have this feature for their respective input components. Maybe have a look at how they did it?

Comment: Or, try preventing the defaults on `@keypress`, that's probably the easiest way to stop certain characters from getting entered.

Comment: I am working with Vue 3 but I'll check it thanks. The problem is wider, since I would like to totally take control of the value, for regex or other purposes, and not let onChange default html behavior to happen at all. Or at least to have total control over it

Comment: yes I am trying the `@keypress` solution thx, I'll tell you if it works

Comment: Actually, `@keypress` worked for me, I just tried :-) Let me know if you need some pointer.

Comment: it works thanks! I am also trying @tao solution, will update when I tried it all

Comment: I posted my own solution but yours works also, you can post it if you'd like some karma ;) Thanks!

Comment: I added my variation. Just an addition to your answers. They are great! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we would use `v-model` to bind the input element two-way, but since you have a slightly different case of something closer to [input masking](https://dev.to/kevinkace/simple-input-mask-b7m), a quick workaround is to perhaps do the input validity check on `keypress` event as opposed to `input` or `change`. Here's a quick demo (BTW, I'm leaving out the Vuex mutation implementation):

```js
Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const foo = Vue.ref('');
    const invalid = Vue.ref(false);
    
    const changeFoo = e => {
      if (!e.target.checkValidity()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        invalid.value = true;
      }
      else {
        invalid.value = false;
      }
    }

    return {
      foo,
      invalid,
      changeFoo
    }
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

```css
.error {
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input 
    v-model="foo" 
    pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
    @keypress="changeFoo" />

  <p v-if="invalid" class="error">Pattern mismatch</p>
</div>
```

You may notice the error message not appearing until the next keystroke gets entered. This is expected behavior and is comparable to the `input` event.

We can fix this by checking against the keystroke instead of the whole input value.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const foo = Vue.ref('');
    const invalid = Vue.ref(false);
    const pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/;
    
    function changeFoo(e) {
      if (!checkValidity(e)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        invalid.value = true;
      }
      else {
        invalid.value = false;
      }
    }
    
    function checkValidity({ keyCode }) {
      return pattern.test(String.fromCharCode(keyCode));
    }

    return {
      pattern,
      foo,
      invalid,
      changeFoo
    }
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

```css
.error {
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input 
    v-model="foo" 
    :pattern="pattern"
    @keypress="changeFoo" />

  <p v-if="invalid" class="error">You pressed a forbidden character!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Yom, I accept this answer as it covers all use cases, even when you want to do async calls before updating the input value.

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped. :-)

Comment: Don't use keypress for validation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbLNU.png And this is without opening the console. You should at least run the validation function on change of value. That's the minimum. For a input mask you have to prevent paste, touch events, mobile input, screen keyboard, etc... You're really a lot better off just using a plugin.

Comment: @tao Did you copy-pasted those on the field? But still, that could be easily tackled by checking the `keyCode` for Ctrl/cmd + V key. But yeah, you might end up having to also handle `mouseup`, etc. But that's what I said, it's a workaround. ;)

Comment: It's a rabbit hole. What about right-click? And, once you're done: how are you going to prevent me from replacing the values on the actual request? When you send it to the server?

Comment: Yep, I mentioned `mouseup` on the previous comment. A fullblown solution would probably involve validating inputs on: keypresses, possibly mousedown/up (unless you have the native context menu suspended somehow) and `blur`/`focus` for double-checking and stripping potentially invalid inputs. Those are more/less what the industry does, no?

Comment: @tao I don't think an input field element/component should be responsible for checking how an HTTP request is sent.

Comment: I believe it's my job as a developer to tell my clients about the pitfalls. It's why they pay me in the first place. Ultimately, it's their choice. But at least I know I did my job well. And, should they still ask for an input mask, I use a versed plugin. The one with most downloads, as it probably has been tested the most.

Comment: @tao Then let's talk about buttons, how do you ensure the actual click action isn't tampered? The possibility is endless. After all, we're talking about UX here, aren't we?

Comment: Input validation is an endless matter. There is no one solution to fit all. If you do your validation on the backend only, your user will only gets his error on the http response, so not real-time, and has to submit the task before any feedback. Backend input validation is mandatory for security reason, it is not sufficient from an UX perspective, at least for the app I want to make.

Comment: Tampering the client side is always possible, so one has to handle common case, after all my user could also directly my input element or mess without intention with the view because of a chrome extension. It's impossible to handle every case.

Comment: That's why you should never override their input. You should only inform them when it's not valid. Your responsibility ends there. That's all I'm saying. If you want a perfect UI consider your user a king. Literally. A royalty. In my estimation, you shouldn't change a king's input. You should helpfully and kindly point out it might not work with that value. It's all about showing the user as much respect as possible.

Comment: yes I understand, also read a well upvoted post on UXstackexchange: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38870/is-constantly-updating-the-formatting-of-a-numeric-input-box-a-good-idea?rq=1. Says that a research shows that any interruption or restriction during a task will slow down the user in his task. Pretty interesting and goes according to your point

Comment: @tao Well, with my approach we're obviously not overriding anything -- we are restricting unwanted inputs. With regard to "informing" your users, are you saying that we are to allow texts on phone/credit card fields when we should be (at least try to) preventing them from getting entered in the first place? I'd say that's a really bad UX.

Comment: If I type something and it doesn't come up in the input box, you're overriding my action. Regardless of whether you stop it between the key and the input or you override it after the input value has changed. That's implementation detail. Irrelevant. And believe me, it is bad UX. I've had the chance to work with amazing UX designers who made me realize how little I knew, coming from a very similar position to yours. To give you an example in this case: I want to input 1e7 into a numeric input. I know what it means, the browser knows what it means. Why should you forbid it? Because you know UX?

Comment: Anyway, the UX principle broken here is: make the user feel empowered rather than powerless. Give them information and choice.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `:value`. Use `v-model` with a computed:

```
<input v-model="foo" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" ref="fooInput">

computed: {
  foo: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.state.foo
    },
    set(value) {
      if (this.$refs.fooInput.checkValidity()) {
         this.$store.commit('CHANGE_FOO', value);
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

In Vue you don't *"take control"*. You ***ref***erence DOM elements.

Here's a way to prevent changing the value of the input when user inputs invalid values. It's considered bad practice.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    storeFoo: null
  }),
  computed: {
    foo: {
      get() {
        return this.storeFoo
      }, 
      set(value) {
        if (this.$refs.fooInput.checkValidity()) {
          this.storeFoo = value;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(e) {
      if (!e.target.checkValidity()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.value = this.storeFoo || null;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="foo" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" ref="fooInput" @input="onInput">
</div>
```

Used a `storeFoo` instead of a proper store prop, for brevity.

---

I should also explain why preventing input changes is bad practice:

As far as UX goes, in a form you want to let the user know when the current value is invalid and why it's invalid, in the friendliest (non-obtrusive) manner possible.

If you override or prevent their actions you show a lack of trust and respect for them.

Comment: Thanks @tao, learned some things about $refs with this methods. However the problem stays the same, for instance you can even get() { return '' } and set(value) { // do nothing }. Input will still updates its value on its own, not overriding the default behavior of the html component. At least in my use case

Comment: I'll try other solutions with getters and setters and let you know

Comment: You don't want to prevent input default behavior. That's frustrating for users and will basically lose you (or your client) money. You should prevent invalid values from being committed and let the user know when their value is invalid. That's what's considered best-practice. Obviously, you could be aggressive and override the input value back to its previous value, but I strongly advise against it. Or you could prevent default. I'll update.

Comment: But apparently, the preventDefault() will only work on the onInput event, the change in value being triggered on keydown event. Also, I don't know for you, but the checkValidity() method is not available on the $refs, only on the event.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. As you can see, it is working as expected. What do you mean is not available in the `$refs`? `$refs.fooInput` returns the actual DOM element. Are you saying the `<input>` element doesn't have a `.checkValidity()` for you? That's highly improbable.

Comment: yep might be something wrong with my code when I tested, your solution works also thanks! I'll go with the mutation directly in the store so it's reusable and everything is located in the store.

Comment: I understand your point about UX, but controlling the default behavior has many other use cases. Also, not allowing certain types of inputs is pretty common practice, it's for example the default behavior of html <input /> type="number", not allowing you to type any text. So I do not agree totally with you on this point.

Comment: displaying an error message is for sure an extra welcomed layer of user friendliness. but it's another subject ;) !

Comment: What I'm saying is pretty common bad practice. But I have absolutely no reason to convince you of this. Also, my personal choice for validation is to have it as close to the `<input>` as possible. Unless I had more than one input source, I'd never place it in the store. The store needs to be as clean as possible and only concerned with data and business logic. With valid data, I might add (already validated). I find this principle to be extremely productive. I find myself coding apps faster with this principle. But it might not be the same for you. I have no idea.

Comment: And, thinking about it, even if I had more than one input source, I'd still not place the validation on store. I'd place it in a utility helper function imported everywhere needed.

Comment: yep I agree with you for the colocation. I may change it back and create a reusable component around <input /> that checks for pattern and returns errors, etc. Good advice

Comment: for the UX point, I think overall you are right, but it depends on the quality of the error message and the type of inputs, for instance it's common practice to not allow anything but numbers in date pickers inputs. Many examples like this. If you have sound errors and it's a simple input, I think disallowing special characters is not a "pretty common bad practice". Could be a little unfriendly, depends of many things! My idea in my function is to automatically replace forbidden characters (space by underscore for instance, etc.). But for another day ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224687/discussion-between-tao-and-quentin-c).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

**First solution found by @Yom S**: as pointed out during our discussion, key related events will all fire before onInput event. You can then preventDefault() on keydown event and concatenate the key value to your current string. I didn't choose it because it's verbose and splits the logic between my mutation and custom methods in component.

**Second solution that I picked**. Not overriding the default behavior, but overwriting it **systematically** in my mutation. So, before:

```
  if (target.checkValidity()) {
    state.foo = { name: target.value };
  }
```

becomes

```
  if (target.checkValidity()) {
    state.foo = { name: value };
  } else {
    state.foo = { name: value.substring(0, value.length - 1) };
  }
```

By always mutating the state each time onInput fires, I am sure that the default input behavior will always be overridden.

NOTE: I will pick the first solution if I have to do async actions before updating my state.

**Third solution**, using setters and getters, see @Tao solution. Same than second solution, not recommended for async calls but less hacky than preventing keypress defaults.